# Sort array and group it with specific value

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array with a lot of values looking like this :
[image]

I'm trying to sort the array by grouping every "part" that have the same `part_image` value and then render the image the value is linked to only 1 single time.

I tried using the groupBy function but without success, does anyone have an approach for this ?

Array variable : `selectedDiam`

**Component.ts**

```
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.filterDrop();
    console.log(this.selectedDiam, ' SELECTED DIAM');
  }

  filterDrop() {
    this.dataDiam1 = this.dataDynParts;
    let dynDiam1 = this.dataDiam1.map(obj => obj.diam[0]);
    dynDiam1 = dynDiam1.filter((v, i) => dynDiam1.indexOf(v) === i);
    this.dataDiam1 = dynDiam1;


    this.dataDiam2 = this.dataDynParts;
    let dynDiam2 = this.dataDiam2.map(obj => obj.diam[1]);
    dynDiam2 = dynDiam2.filter((v, i) => dynDiam2.indexOf(v) === i);
    this.dataDiam2 = dynDiam2;


    this.createForm();
    this.filteredWithDiam = this.dataDynParts;
    this.selectedDiam = this.dataDynParts;
    this.quotationIdNumber = this.quotationId;
  }
```

**Component.html**

```
<div class="products">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row linesColor ml-2" *ngFor="let products of selectedDiam; let  i = index;">
    <a class="flex1">HERE IS WHERE THE PHOTO SHOULD BE RENDERED</a>
    <a class="flex1">{{products.l3_label}}</a>
    <a class="flex1">{{products.diam[0]}}</a>
    <a class="flex1">{{products.diam[1]}}</a>
    <a class="flex1">
      <input class="number" ngModel="{{products.longueur}}"  (ngModelChange)="postQuotationDatas($event,products,'longueur')" type="number">
    </a>
    <input class="mb-1 flex1 checkbox" ngModel="{{products.hasValve}}"  (ngModelChange)="postQuotationDatas($event,products,'hasValve')" type="checkbox">
    <a class="flex1 mb-1">
      <input class="number" ngModel="{{products.quantity}}"  (ngModelChange)="postQuotationDatas($event,products,'quantity')" type="number">
    </a>
    <a class="flex1">
      {{(products.total_fourniture)}}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a dummy input object with expected output object seems like you need to write a custom function for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following snippet:

```js
// assume arr refers to your array of data
const groups = {}; // for storing groups while processing
arr.forEach(v => {
    if(groups[v.part_image]) 
        groups [v.part_image].push(v.image); // the actual image values you want to group
    else groups[v.part_image] = [ v.image ];
});
// Now you can process each image and all its parts
```

You can iterate over all the keys in the object. `Object.keys(groups)` for that.

Comment: you missed closing bracket for `if` block

Comment: Thank's a lot! That's a really nice input, so in order to render the image only one time on the front I use `Object.keys(groups)` after, right ?

Comment: @Zephyr yes. Once you call `Object.keys(groups)` it will return all the keys for the groups object. The keys are in "random" order. If you need to sort them in any way, you can try to chain `sort()` after getting the keys. You can read each object as `Object.keys(groups).forEach(k => grouos[k]);`. Hope that explains. If you need more help, please comment. If the snippet solves your issue, then mark as accepted. Thanks