# How to restructure all data-items of an array by grouping them via main-key and collecting all of a group's remaining entries as grouped value-lists?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, data-structures, reduce

I am having a problem with merging objects in an array by key and the grouping the values that have the same key in arrays. Example:

```js
let a = [{
    key: "1",
    value: "a",
    value2: "b"
}, {
    key: "2",
    value: "a",
    value2: "b"
}, {
    key: "1",
    value: "b",
    value2: "a"
}, {
    key: "1",
    value: "c",
    value2: "d"
}]
```

The results that I want to achieve is:

```js
[{
    key: "1",
    value: ["a", "b", "c"],
    value2: ["b", "a", "d"]
}, {
    key: "2",
    value: ["a"],
    value2: ["b"]
}]
```

Does anyone have a simple solution for this in javascript/typescript?

I have read quite a few threads about similar issues, but none that are the exact same as the one I have above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share code that you have written and the problems with your solution. That can help others to understand your problem. For grouping you can look at this for a possible approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64715927/sort-array-and-group-it-with-specific-value/64716113#64716113

Comment: What have you tried so far, at which point got you stuck? Maybe you already have some code that you were fiddling around with?..show us ...

Comment: Marked as solved now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this. It first reduces the data to a key based object and transform it to your array after.

```js
var a = [{key:"1", value:"a",value2:"b"}, {key:"2", value:"a",value2:"b"}, {key:"1", value:"b",value2:"a"},{key:"1", value:"c",value2:"d"}]

a = a.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.key]) {
    acc[curr.key] = { value: [curr.value], value2: [curr.value2] };
  } else {
    acc[curr.key].value.push(curr.value);
    acc[curr.key].value2.push(curr.value2);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

a = Object.entries(a).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, ...value }))

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to do this without having to specify each key when defining the object? For example with a object.entries loop? I tried that before, but using the object[key] gave me all kinds of errors in typescript, which is why I had to start this thread.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = [{key:"1", value:"a",value2:"b"}, {key:"2", value:"a",value2:"b"}, {key:"1", value:"b",value2:"a"},{key:"1", value:"c",value2:"d"}]

const result = a.reduce((res, item) => {
  let trans = res.find(e => e.key === item.key) || res.push(item) && item ;
  Object.entries(item).map(([key, val]) => {
      if(key !== "key") {
        trans[key] = Array.isArray(trans[key]) ? [...trans[key], val]: [val];
      }
    });
  return res;
}, []);

console.log('result', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic approach is implemented in a way that it just considers the main data structure of a common transformation task. It will be always agnostic about the (final) grouping key, but it does implement a configuration option for the latter.

Thus one might come up with an approach which is based on two [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#How_reduce_works) methods, one for collecting the groups by the provided group-`key` value and another one for collecting entry-values into (grouped) lists ...

```js
function collectEntryValueAsListItem(accumulator, entry) {
  const [key, value] = entry;

  const valueList = accumulator[key] || (accumulator[key] = []);
  valueList.push(value);

  return accumulator;
}
function groupDataByKeyAndCollectEntryValues(collector, item) {
  const { key, index, list } = collector;
  const groupKey = item[key];

  let groupItem = index[groupKey];
  if (!groupItem) {

    groupItem = index[groupKey] = { [key]: groupKey };
    list.push(groupItem);
  }
  item = Object.assign({}, item);
  delete item[key];

  Object
    .entries(item)
    .reduce(collectEntryValueAsListItem, groupItem);

  return collector;
}


const sampleList = [
  { key: "1", value: "a", value2: "b" },
  { key: "2", value: "a", value2: "b" },
  { key: "1", value: "b", value2: "a" },
  { key: "1", value: "c", value2: "d" },
];

console.log(
  '... the result which the OP was looking for ...',
  sampleList.reduce(groupDataByKeyAndCollectEntryValues, {

    key: 'key',
    index: {},
    list: [],

  }).list
);

console.log(
  '... 2nd proof of the generic reduce approach ...',
  sampleList.reduce(groupDataByKeyAndCollectEntryValues, {

    key: 'value',
    index: {},
    list: [],

  }).list
);
console.log(
  '... 3rd proof of the generic reduce approach ...',
  sampleList.reduce(groupDataByKeyAndCollectEntryValues, {

    key: 'value2',
    index: {},
    list: [],

  }).list
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```